# Random corruption of MFT in external drives require CHKDSK for fix

Tags: ntfs, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption, mft

I have this problem for months now.

I am getting my external drives MFT corrupt. When i run CHKDSK afterwards, most of the time i get the files back in their places.

I have changed external disks + cables multiple times, disabled indexing in Windows.

Usually i am alarmed for the situation after running a freeware utility for file sync (freefilesync).

Here is the output of today's CHKDSK:

```
Chkdsk was executed in read/write mode.  

Checking file system on E:
Volume dismounted.  All opened handles to this volume are now invalid.
Volume label is PANOPLIAS1.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1cdec for possibly 0x40 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5bb6f is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5BB6F.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce2c for possibly 0x3 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5c6e6 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5C6E6.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce2f for possibly 0x8 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5c73f is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5C73F.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce37 for possibly 0x2 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5d9a4 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5D9A4.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce39 for possibly 0x3 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5e1b9 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5E1B9.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce3c for possibly 0x3 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5e1bc is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5E1BC.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce3f for possibly 0xa clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5e1be is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5E1BE.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce49 for possibly 0x3 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5e1ee is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5E1EE.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce4c for possibly 0xa clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5e6f3 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5E6F3.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce56 for possibly 0x2 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5eaa2 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5EAA2.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce58 for possibly 0x2 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5eaa5 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5EAA5.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce5a for possibly 0x2 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5eae6 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5EAE6.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce5c for possibly 0x4 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5eae9 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5EAE9.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce60 for possibly 0x4 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5eaea is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5EAEA.
Attribute record of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3 is cross linked
starting at 0x1ce64 for possibly 0x2 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0xa0 and instance tag 0x3
in file 0x5eb4a is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0xA0, $I30)
from file record segment 0x5EB4A.
  388864 file records processed.                                                         File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 4.79 seconds.
  21 large file records processed.                                     Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.                                       Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 38.59 milliseconds.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
The file reference 0x3000000037027 of index entry sync.ffs_db of index $I30
with parent 0x5 is not the same as 0x4000000037027.
Deleting index entry sync.ffs_db in index $I30 of file 5.
The file reference 0x3000000037027 of index entry SYNC~2.FFS of index $I30
with parent 0x5 is not the same as 0x4000000037027.
Deleting index entry SYNC~2.FFS in index $I30 of file 5.
  3 reparse records processed.                                       Index entry [KMIA] Miami int 1.01.rar of index $I30 in file 0x3432b points to unused file 0x3cfc4.
Deleting index entry [KMIA] Miami int 1.01.rar in index $I30 of file 3432B.
Index entry _KMIA_~1.RAR of index $I30 in file 0x3432b points to unused file 0x3cfc4.
Deleting index entry _KMIA_~1.RAR in index $I30 of file 3432B.
The VCN 0x14 of index $I30 in file 0x46380 is already in use.
The VCN 0x15 of index $I30 in file 0x46380 is already in use.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 46380.
The index bitmap $I30 in file 0x46380 is incorrect.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 46380.
The down pointer of current index entry with length 0xe0 is invalid.
4b ee 05 00 00 00 03 00 e0 00 c6 00 01 00 00 00  Kî......à.......
80 63 04 00 00 00 01 00 02 64 ef 51 f6 aa d6 01  €c.......dïQöª..
6a a8 7d 63 f4 aa d6 01 90 dc 35 b1 fd aa d6 01  j¨}côª...5.ýª..
7b b5 35 b1 fd aa d6 01 00 e0 07 00 00 00 00 00  {.5.ýª...à......
28 d4 07 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  (....... .......
42 01 4d 00 69 00 63 00 72 00 6f 00 73 00 6f 00  B.M.i.c.r.o.s.o.
66 00 74 00 20 00 46 00 6c 00 69 00 67 00 68 00  f.t. .F.l.i.g.h.
74 00 20 00 53 00 69 00 6d 00 75 00 6c 00 61 00  t. .S.i.m.u.l.a.
74 00 6f 00 72 00 20 00 53 00 63 00 72 00 65 00  t.o.r. .S.c.r.e.
65 00 6e 00 73 00 68 00 6f 00 74 00 20 00 32 00  e.n.s.h.o.t. .2.
30 00 32 00 30 00 2e 00 31 00 30 00 2e 00 32 00  0.2.0...1.0...2.
35 00 20 00 2d 00 20 00 31 00 34 00 2e 00 31 00  5. .-. .1.4...1.
38 00 2e 00 30 00 38 00 2e 00 35 00 35 00 2e 00  8...0.8...5.5...
6a 00 70 00 67 00 31 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  j.p.g.1.ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
Sorting index $I30 in file 46380.
Index entry MI513E~2.JPG of index $I30 in file 0x46380 points to unused file 0x2efb.
Deleting index entry MI513E~2.JPG in index $I30 of file 46380.
Index entry MI9E57~2.JPG of index $I30 in file 0x46380 points to unused file 0x2efd.
Deleting index entry MI9E57~2.JPG in index $I30 of file 46380.
A downpointer (VCN 0x6) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5bb6f but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5BB6F.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5BB6F.
A downpointer (VCN 0x0) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5c6e6 but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5C6E6.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5C6E6.
A downpointer (VCN 0x6) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5c73f but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5C73F.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5C73F.
A downpointer (VCN 0x0) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5d9a4 but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5D9A4.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5D9A4.
A downpointer (VCN 0x0) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5e1b9 but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5E1B9.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5E1B9.
A downpointer (VCN 0x0) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5e1bc but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5E1BC.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5E1BC.
A downpointer (VCN 0x5) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5e1be but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5E1BE.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5E1BE.
A downpointer (VCN 0x0) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5e1ee but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5E1EE.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5E1EE.
A downpointer (VCN 0x5) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5e6f3 but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5E6F3.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5E6F3.
A downpointer (VCN 0x0) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5eaa2 but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5EAA2.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5EAA2.
A downpointer (VCN 0x0) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5eaa5 but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5EAA5.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5EAA5.
A downpointer (VCN 0x0) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5eae6 but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5EAE6.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5EAE6.
A downpointer (VCN 0x0) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5eae9 but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5EAE9.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5EAE9.
A downpointer (VCN 0x0) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5eaea but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5EAEA.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5EAEA.
A downpointer (VCN 0x0) was found in index $I30 in file 0x5eb4a but the index has no index allocation attribute.
Removing corrupt index $I30 in file 5EB4A.
Recreating deleted index $I30 in file 5EB4A.
Index entry IMAGE$23C76FBDA13120D2.gif of index $I30 in file 0x5eddb points to unused file 0x5ee92.
Deleting index entry IMAGE$23C76FBDA13120D2.gif in index $I30 of file 5EDDB.
Index entry IMAGE$~1.GIF of index $I30 in file 0x5eddb points to unused file 0x5ee92.
Deleting index entry IMAGE$~1.GIF in index $I30 of file 5EDDB.
  493012 index entries processed.                                                        Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 2.22 minutes.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
Recovering orphaned file Chkdsk (11) into directory file 26.
Recovering orphaned file SYNC~2.FFS (263) into directory file 5.
Recovering orphaned file AB4EDI~1.TXT (5C3D8) into directory file 5BB6F.
Recovering orphaned file Ab4editAR.txt (5C3D8) into directory file 5BB6F.
Recovering orphaned file AB4EDI~2.TXT (5C3D9) into directory file 5BB6F.
Recovering orphaned file Ab4editBG.txt (5C3D9) into directory file 5BB6F.
Recovering orphaned file AB4EDI~3.TXT (5C3DA) into directory file 5BB6F.
Recovering orphaned file Ab4editCA.txt (5C3DA) into directory file 5BB6F.
Recovering orphaned file AB4EDI~4.TXT (5C3DB) into directory file 5BB6F.
Recovering orphaned file Ab4editEL.txt (5C3DB) into directory file 5BB6F.
Skipping further messages about recovering orphans.

  1375 unindexed files recovered to original directory.
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 0.00 milliseconds.
CHKDSK is recovering remaining unindexed files.

    Lost and found is located at \found.000

 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 0.00 milliseconds.
  3 reparse records processed.                                        Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 4.13 milliseconds.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Repairing the security file record segment.
Deleting an index entry with Id 106 from index $SII of file 9.
Deleting an index entry with Id 107 from index $SII of file 9.
Deleting an index entry with Id 115 from index $SII of file 9.
Deleting an index entry with Id 106 from index $SDH of file 9.
Deleting an index entry with Id 107 from index $SDH of file 9.
Deleting an index entry with Id 115 from index $SDH of file 9.
Cleaning up 7 unused index entries from index $SII of file 9.
Cleaning up 7 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 9.
Cleaning up 7 unused security descriptors.
Security descriptor verification completed.
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 39.86 milliseconds.
  52074 data files processed.                                             Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 1.70 milliseconds.
Correcting errors in the master file table's (MFT) BITMAP attribute.
Correcting errors in the Volume Bitmap.

Windows has made corrections to the file system.
No further action is required.

 976760407 KB total disk space.
 375180676 KB in 336514 files.
    148428 KB in 52062 indexes.
    484675 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 600946628 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 244190101 total allocation units on disk.
 150236657 allocation units available on disk.
Total duration: 2.33 minutes (140229 ms).
```

**Smartctl -a output:**

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-w10-b19041] (sf-7.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ04UBF... (USB 3.0)
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ04UBF100
Serial Number:    DIRTYSECRET
LU WWN Device Id: 0 000000 000000000
Firmware Version: JU003U
User Capacity:    1.000.204.886.016 bytes [1,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Oct 27 09:04:32 2020 GTBST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Disabled

SMART Disabled. Use option -s with argument 'on' to enable it.
(override with '-T permissive' option)
```

Comment: Are you safely ejecting? Can you pull the drive and put it into another cabinet? Sounds like a controller issue or the drive is on the way out.

Comment: I am safely removing. I have also changed 3 external disk with their cables...

Comment: Run SMART tests on the drives.

Comment: @DavidPostill Everything seems in order....

Comment: @e4rthdog Please post the S.M.A.R.T results: `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` _(remove device serial # before posting please)_

Comment: @JW0914 I added in the post the output of the command

Answer (score 0):

This happens mostly due to incorrect shutdown & hardware failure.

I personally get 1 case per month at least in my infra where user shutdown the server with direct power off (in vm also).

I don't know if you solved the problem but your problem was mostly hardware related. Once corrupted it is not easily repairable only option is to reinstall windows on re-formatted disk or partition.

Comment: Welcome to superuser; You have answered using information from the comments , you maybe correct but it is best as a comment Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. again welcome to superuser and keep coming back.